# Determine United Airlines status level using worksheet functions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets, iwork-numbers

[United Airlines MileagePlus Premier status levels are determined by a combination of criteria:](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/mileageplus/premier/qualify.aspx)

- Silver: `(PQM>=25000 OR PQS>=30) AND PQD>=3000`
- Gold: `(PQM>=50000 OR PQS>=60) AND PQD>=6000`
- Platinum:`(PQM>=75000 OR PQS>=90) AND PQD>=9000`
- 1K: `(PQM>=100000 OR PQS>=120) AND PQD>=12000`

I have columns with the PQM, PQS and PQD totals. I'd like a formula to display the status level (e.g. "Gold"). Do I need a complex set of nested IF statements? Do I do a lookup somehow?

Comment: You've specified several different spreadsheet applications. Is there any preference?

Comment: I would do (and just did) the nested `IF`s myself, would be interested to know if there's a better way too. I'm assuming you don't need answers showing how to structure that nested `IF` solution?

Comment: @bwDraco I am using Numbers on MacOS. Function for that would be ideal, but I could adapt one if you are more confortable with Excel or Google Sheets.

Comment: @3N1GM4 I have been fiddling with the nested IFs, but getting a lot of errors. If you have it working, I'd really appreciate a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another approach using `INDEX` and `MATCH`, it's a more abstract, but also shorter formula based on your logic:

`=INDEX(Table1[LEVEL],MIN(MAX(MATCH(B9,Table1[PQM]),MATCH(C9,Table1[PQS])),MATCH(D9,Table1[PQD])))`

> (PQM>=25000 OR PQS>=30) AND PQD>=3000

- `PQM>=25000 OR PQS>=30` - the higher level reached by PQM or PQS => MAX
- `(...) AND PQD>=3000` - the lower level reached by previous selection and PQD

[image]

Or just the formula without helper table:

`=INDEX({"--","Silver","Gold","Platinum","1k"},MIN(MAX(MATCH(B9,{0,25000,50000,75000,100000}),MATCH(C9,{0,30,60,90,120})),MATCH(D9,{0,3000,6000,9000,12000})))`

Answer (score 2):

So if you did want to go with the nested `IF` solution, you could create a small lookup table like this:

[image: Lookup Table]

And then if you have your `PQM`, `PQS` and `PQD` values in `B8`, `C8` and `D8` respectively, the formula would be:

`=IF(AND(OR(B8>$B$5,C8>$C$5),D8>$D$5),$A$5,IF(AND(OR(B8>$B$4,C8>$C$4),D8>$D$4),$A$4,IF(AND(OR(B8>$B$3,C8>$C$3),D8>$D$3),$A$3,IF(AND(OR(B8>$B$2,C8>$C$2),D8>$D$2),$A$2,"None"))))`

You could just as easily replace the table references with hard coded values if you'd rather not have the lookup table (although I prefer having it in case you need to change the parameters of the calculation in the future):

`=IF(AND(OR(B8>100000,C8>120),D8>12000),"1K",IF(AND(OR(B8>75000,C8>90),D8>9000),"Platinum",IF(AND(OR(B8>50000,C8>60),D8>6000),"Gold",IF(AND(OR(B8>25000,C8>30),D8>3000),"Silver","None"))))`

Hopefully it's fairly obvious how this works, it's checking for the highest level conditions first, then if they're not satisfied, working its way down the levels until it finds one which is, returning `"None"` if there is no applicable level to return.